# Uncaught TypeError: a.data.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array que tiene información que necesito imprimirlo en un html, en un archivo de javascript estoy intentando obtener los valores del array mediante un forEach, a continuacion el detalle:

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    _element: {
      type: Object,
      notify: true,
      value: function () {
        return {};
      }
      },
      books: {
        type: Array,
        value: [],
        notify: true
      }
    }
  };

dataLoaded(element) {
  this.set('_element', element);
  let filter = [];
  this.set('books', []);


  element.data.forEach(item => {
    filter.push({
    'id': item.id
    })
  });

  this.set('books', filter);
}
```

Comment: `element.data` ??? estas seguro que es data la propiedad a la que estas accediendo ? , por que no la tienes declarada en ninguna parte por eso mismo te genera el error , deberias de  acceder a `books: {` que es el que tienes como array .

Answer (score 13):

En JavaScript `forEach()` es una función de un **iterable**, puede ser un [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach), [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) o un [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) por mencionar algunos, por lo que primero debes asegurarte que a la variable que estás aplicando esa función sea un iterable

Si tu variable es, digamos, un objeto, la función `forEach()` no estará disponible, te pongo un ejemplo

```js
const anObject = {
  name: "Carlos",
  lastname: "Proaño",
  city: "Mérida"
};

anObject.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

No pasa lo mismo con un arreglo

```js
const anArray = [
  'peras',
  'manzanas',
  'naranjas',
  'uvas',
];

anArray.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Si estás intentando aplicar el `forEach()` a un objeto primero lo debes convertir a un arreglo si no es obligatorio el soporte para IE o tienes un transpilador como Babel puedes utilizar [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), por otro lado si no tienes un transpilador y necesitas dar soporte a IE puedes utilizar un [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), pondré el ejemplo de la documentación adaptado para mostrar la funcionalidad del `Object.values()`

```js
let string1 = "";
let string2 = "";
const object1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

for (let property1 in object1) {
  string1 += object1[property1];
}

Object.values(object1).forEach(item => {string2 += item});

console.log(string1);
console.log(string2);
```

Por último **si necesitas regresar un arreglo como resultado de la iteración** te recomendaría utilizar [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const fruits = [
  {id: 1, value: 'peras'},
  {id: 2, value: 'naranjas'},
  {id: 3, value: 'manzanas'},
  {id: 4, value: 'uvas'},
];

const newArray = fruits.map(item => item.id);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: por ejemplo si se trata de iterar sobre un objeto y obtener el valor de alguna de sus propiedades, se pudiera hacer con `for of`, es así o entendí mal la pregunta @KacosPro

Comment: @Aprendiz ses correcto, pero me enfoqué más en responder porque da el error de `forEach is not a function` y de como la podemos utilizar solo si convertimos el objeto en un arreglo, no me enfoqué en presentar formas de iterar sobre un objeto.

Comment: entiendo y es totalmente acertada tu respuesta, solo quería tenerlo claro pues me gustaría dar una respuesta que mas bien solo complementaría la tuya

Comment: Por favor hazlo :) de mi parte tendrás un +1

Answer (score 5):

El método `forEach` se ejecuta sobre un `vector` de valores por lo que si devuelve un mensaje del tipo:

> .... forEach is not a function

Quiere decir que ese elemento no es un arreglo, como ya tienes una excelente respuesta arriba, solo te complementaré con lo siguiente:

**El bucle `for-of`**

Nos permite recorrer los elementos de un objeto o de un vector:

**Ejemplo 1**

Iterando sobre los elementos de un vector que contiene elementos de distinto tipo

```js
    let elementos = ["a", "b", true, new Date()];
    
    for (elemento of elementos) {
      console.log(elemento);
    }
```

Dando como salida:

> ```
> "a"
> "b"
> true
> [object Date] { ... }
> ```

**Ejemplo 2**

Iterando sobre los elementos de un objeto

```js
    const data = [
      {id: 1, name: "uno"},
      {id: 2, name: "dos"},
      {id: 3, name: "tres"}
    ]
    
    for (elemento of data){
      console.log(elemento.name)
    }
```

Dando como resultado:

> ```
> "uno"
> "dos"
> "tres"
> ```

De los ejemplos anteriores, podemos diferenciar que:

- Cuando se itera sobre un `vector` solamente se imprime la variable que recupera el valor por cada recorrido del mismo
- Cuando se itera sobre un objeto, se imprime la variable y para poder acceder a un elemento específico lo hacemos por medio de su `clave` que en este caso es `name` a través de la sintaxis de: `variable.clave`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que no estas agregando al [path](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/api/namespaces/Polymer.Path) el valor que le corresponde en los valores, te puedes ayudar con los mixins para el manejo de los paths en polymer que son los siguientes [arrays en polymer](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/model-data#work-with-arrays), para tu caso en especifico podrías utilizar

`this.push('books', { 'id': item.id });` y recuerda utilizar correctamente el `notify: true` ya que puedes tener comportamientos inesperados si realizas un cambio desde el `host`.

Saludos.